# Solution of the recurrence $a_n-3a_{n-1}=2^n$, $a_0=5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

> What is the solution of the recurrence $a_n-3a_{n-1}=2^n$, $a_0=5$.

I think the solution is 
$$a_n=3^n(5)+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}3^{n-i}2^i+2^n.$$
Am I right? Can it be simplified further? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right, your formula can be further simplified. Note that the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}3^{n-i}2^i=3^n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(2/3)^i$ is [geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula). Finally you should obtain
$$a_n=A\cdot 3^n+B\cdot 2^n$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants to be determined.
Can you take it from here?

Comment: thanks, can we use recursion tree here? Or is this somewhat similar to linear difference equation?

Comment: You already used the recursion tree to find $3^n(5)+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}3^{n-i}2^i+2^n$. Now it is an algebraic matter.

Comment: it's not proven though?

Comment: @miniparser What do you mean?

Comment: Just that the solution is given but not really proven?

Comment: @miniparser I don't think so, the "recursion tree" can be considered as an induction proof of $a_n=3^n(5)+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}3^{n-i}2^i+2^n$